# SQL Group By groups of n?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to group some rows in a database, in groups of n.

**Example:**

```
select max(data) from tableA group by (groups of 2) order by id;
```

**result:** 20, 30, 5

*so...*

group 1 holds id 1 & 2, group 2 holds id 3 & 4, and group 3 would hold id 5 & 6.

```
tableA
| id  |  data |     
---------------
| 1   | 10    |
| 2   | 20    |
| 3   | 15    |
| 4   | 30    |
| 5   | 5     |
| 6   | 0     |
---------------
```

Is there a way to achieve this using SQL?

**Note:** The system is running on MySql.

Comment: `group 3 would hold id 4 & 6` or `group 3 would hold id 5 & 6` ?

Comment: group 3 holds 5 & 6, I fixed the typo, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `GROUP BY` can hold an arbitrary expression, you can use `CASE` to return the `id` if its value `MOD 2` is equal to 1, and `id - 1` otherwise. This groups them in pairs incrementing from 1.

```
SELECT MAX(data) AS maxdata
FROM tableA
/* GROUP BY the id or (id - 1) depending on the result of its modulo 2 */
GROUP BY CASE WHEN id MOD 2 = 1 THEN id ELSE (id - 1) END
```

#### [Here is a demo on SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff45d/6)

### Allow for non-sequential ids

#### Update

Overnight I felt badly about the fact that this solution only works correctly for *sequential* values of `id`. If you deleted rows, you would no longer get correct results.  So here is a version that accounts for non-sequential, gapped `id`s:

```
SET @rowid = 0;
SELECT 
  MAX(data) AS maxdata
FROM (
  SELECT  
    @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS rd,
    data
  FROM tableA
) subq
GROUP BY CASE WHEN rd MOD 2 = 1 THEN rd ELSE (rd - 1) END
```

[And the updated SQLfiddle...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bec4/2)

Answer (score 5):

```
select
    (mod(id, 2) + id)/2 as id_group,
    max(data) as max_data
from tableA
group by 1
```

See this query running in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff45d/30)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it is correct now. I redacted question as sum, but he wants max. Fixed now